# How to add #include <winrt/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h> to CMake

Tags: cmake, c++-winrt

I'm trying to change my Win32 window background color from light to dark mode but I'm having issues trying to get

```
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h>
```

working how do I add that include to CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(BOLTgui VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(BOLTgui main.cpp)
```

Comment: you don't add header files in your CMake file, add the `#incldue` to your `.cpp` or `.h` files where needed

Comment: @TedLyngmo its C++/WinRT

Comment: `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h` doesn't sound like a valid file name. Also, can you clarify what you mean by *how do I add that include to CMake*? do you mean adding the include directory, or adding the header file to the file list?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget As far as I know, it's a very valid filename you can have as many dots as you want

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Oops, I guess I was confused by the dots in the filename.

Comment: The specific challenge here isn't instructing CMake to include any particular header file. It's generating the header file to begin with. You will have to run *cppwinrt.exe* after downloading the [Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT) NuGet package.